# Gridview find control in dynamic header row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This may have to do with the page life cycle but just can't seem to get it working, even after finding every post out there on the subject.

In a gridview, a new header row is created with a control:

```
protected void gvNotes_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();

        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Text = "Show Admin Columns";            
        chk.ID = "chk";
        chk.AutoPostBack = true;            
        chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.chkShowAminColumns_CheckedChanged);

        HeaderCell.Controls.Add(chk);                   
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = gvNotes.Columns.Count;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
        gvNotes.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
    }
}
```

Trying to find this new control is giving me a little trouble:

```
public void bindNotesGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = BLL.NotesBLL.GetNotes();
    gvNotes.DataSource = dt;
    gvNotes.DataBind();         


    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //never finds the control
        foreach (Control c in gvNotes.HeaderRow.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                string value = ((CheckBox)c).Text;
            }
        }

        //never finds the control
        //int current = 0;
        //int headerCount = gvNotes.HeaderRow.Cells.Count;

        //for (current = 0; current < headerCount; current++)
        //{
        //    CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox)gvNotes.HeaderRow.Cells[current].FindControl("chk");               
        //}

        //returns null
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvNotes.HeaderRow.FindControl("chk");

    }
}
```

All the findcontrol attempts return the checkbox as null.
What am I not seeing here?

Thanks!

Comment: First - make sure you are using the same table, why are you looking throught `gvCollapseNotes` when you've added the control to `gvNotes` ?  Second, you are adding a second header row, but in both cases you are only looking through 1 Header row, not both

Comment: Also, you are binding `gvCollapseNotes` and not `gvNotes`

Comment: It's gvNotes. Fixed the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The header row is generated by the GridView control based on your data source.  It is not actually a member of your dataset but is dynamically built based on the contents of the data set.

Consider this code:

```
    int HeaderRowCount = -5;  // initialized to a wrong starting point

    protected void GridView1_DataBinding( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        HeaderRowCount = 0;  // this event starts the binding and row creation process
    }

    // Each row is created and Bound in the order of the dataset.
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e ) {

        // Are we creating the Header Row?
        if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header ) {

            // Create your additional Headers here:  AddHeaderRow() is defined below
            AddHeaderRow( ( GridView ) sender, "Hi I'm a header" );
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e ) {
        if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header ) {
            HeaderRowCount++;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_DataBound( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        GridView1.Caption = string.Format( "HeaderRowCount: {0}", HeaderRowCount);
    }
```

---

After binding is complete you will see this in the GridView Caption:

*HeaderRowCount: 1*

The header row count will always be 1 because additional header rows are not part of the binding process.  The GridView Rows collection only contain Rows that are part of the DataSet.  GridViews generate the `HeaderRow` (and `FooterRow`) dynamically.

Any additional Header Rows are only available through the inner Table collection of rows, so you need to search each Table Row for `RowType == Header`:

```
    Table InnerTable = ( Table ) GridView1.Controls[ 0 ];

    foreach ( GridViewRow r in InnerTable.Rows ) {
        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header){
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) r.FindControl( "chk" );
        }
    }
```

Or you can access the rows directly if you wish:

```
    GridViewRow r = ( GridViewRow ) InnerTable.Rows[0];
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) r.FindControl( "chk" );
```

---

#### AddHeaderRow()

```
    private void AddHeaderRow( GridView gv, string HeaderText ) {
        Table InnerTable = ( Table ) gv.Controls[ 0 ];

        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow( 0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal );
        TableCell th = new TableHeaderCell();


        th.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        th.ColumnSpan = gv.Columns.Count;
        th.Font.Bold = true;
        th.Text = HeaderText;

        row.Cells.Add( th );

        InnerTable.Rows.AddAt( 0, row );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the control try this:-

```
foreach (Control c in gvNotes.Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)c.FindControl("chk");
        }
```

> gvNotes.Controls[0].Controls  -> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table.**RowControlCollection**
>
> gvNotes.Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls  ->  System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow.**CellControlCollection**

as first you added TableRow and then TableCell

Hop this will help